# Is there a way to dynamically add items to a form based on the number of subroutines in a module?

Tags: vba, autocad

I'm working in IntelliCAD but if you have the know how for ACAD, I wanna hear it cause they're all the same. I'm making a `userform` for users to run some routines, and wanted to make a listbox that would dynamically add items based on how many `subroutines` it sees under a `module`. The problem I've hit is that as the subroutines are not stored in a `collection / array`, I can't `For Each` through them. And that's a problem cause if it isn't one of those I don't know what it is or how to access all the members.

[image]

Alright I've come up with some code that can see the subroutines within projects, as well as differentiate between private and public subs (self explanatory, but its cause I don't want users to be able to see private subs in the form). Shoutout to braX for helping me out, I don't know how to set something as the answer so I'm resorting to edits.

```
Dim ProcKind As VBIDE.vbext_ProcKind
Dim StartLine As Long
Dim EndLine As Long
Sub CountCode()
' All ints in this code are arbitrary and just what worked for me
For Each vbproj In Application.VBE.vbprojects
    If vbproj.Name = "CommonProjects" Then
        For Each component In vbproj.VBComponents
            With component.CodeModule
                If .CountOfLines > 3 Then ' This just filters out my own garbage
                    LineNum = .CountOfDeclarationLines + 3 ' Line numbers are calc'd after compilation so really I don't know wtf is happening
                    LineNum = .procStartLine(.procOfLine(LineNum, ProcKind), ProcKind)
                    Do Until LineNum >= .CountOfLines
                        StartLine = LineNum
                        EndLine = LineNum + 3
                        procName = .ProcOfLine(LineNum, ProcKind)
                        If .Find("Private", StartLine, 1, EndLine, 3) Then ' Ok the ints here are actually good tho. No need to search all columns when 'private' is gonna appear in the first one
                            MsgBox("Private: " & procName & vbNewLine & vbNewLine & "LineNum: " & LineNum)
                        Else
                            MsgBox ("Public: " & procName & vbNewLine & vbNewLine & "LineNum: " & LineNum)
                        End If
                        LineNum = .procStartLine(procName, ProcKind) + .ProcCountLines(procName, ProcKind) + 1

                    Loop
                End If
            End With
        Next
    End If
Next

End Sub
```

Comment: You will need to adjust the code to work in the IntelliCAD environment instead of Excel, but this demonstrates how you can do it - https://www.vitoshacademy.com/vba-listing-all-procedures-in-all-modules/

Comment: Test it out in Excel first to make sure it works, and adjust the code to simply count them instead of listing them, then after getting that working, converting it to work IntelliCAD should be fairly simple.

Comment: And by "it" - i mean counting the routines. I would approach that first. Adding controls to a form would be a separate issue to address afterwards, as there would be a lot of things to consider doing that. http://www.vbaexpress.com/kb/getarticle.php?kb_id=202

Comment: Alright, these led me down he right track. I'm working with VB7.1 so maybe thats why, but I don't see the VBIDE obj / property, instead there is a VBE property present in the application. The really annoying thing is that the IDE baked into IntelliCAD doesn't even know what members VBE has, so I have to look for what properties and methods exist in Excel, then blindly type it out in IntelliCAD and only when I run do I know if its working. Anyhow, thanks for the quick response, I think I'll be good from here.

Comment: If you want to use intellisense you need to use early binding instead of late binding. Add an Excel reference to IntelliCAD and then it will be "aware" of the Excel object model like you are used to. When you are done, you can always switch it back to late binding.

Comment: Thanks, but that wasn't the problem. I have the reference set for Excel and it works great, the trouble is that if I go 'IntelliCAD.Application.VBE.' intellisense doesn't know what comes next. The VBE object was never properly added to their object tree would be my guess. I can still go deeper (ie Application.VBE.VBProjects) but it never gives me the possibilities, and even after compiling it doesn't have proper capitalization, but it still works :) .

Comment: Another good reference in case someone stumbles here in the future is [this link](http://www.vbaexpress.com/forum/archive/index.php/t-36034.html).